# Can Graduation be translated as 毕业 only？

Tags: translation

最不发达国家指联合国指定的、尚未从最不发达国家的类型中**毕业**的任何国家

Least Developed Country means any country designated as such by the United Nations and which has not obtained **graduation** from the least developed country category

From: CHAPTER 1 INITIAL PROVISIONS AND GENERAL DEFINITIONS, REGIONAL COMPREHENSIVE ECONOMIC PARTNERSHIP (RCEP)AGREEMENT

A Least Developed Country is studying under the United Nations? Can 毕业 be used here? Is there anything wrong with the official Chinese text given as above?

Comment: It is a figure of speech, the term 'graduated' can metaphor "move on" or "grow out of something"

Answer (score 1):

毕业: 引申指小结、**休止**

最不发达国家指联合国指定的、尚未从最不发达国家的类型中毕业的任何国家.
Least Developed Countries refers to (countries) designated by the United Nations as not yet having graduated from the category Least Developed Countries.

Officialese to English translation:

If a country is categorised as a member of the Least Developed Countries Category, it has not yet stopped being a member of the  Least Developed Countries Category.

A truly wonderful language, Officialese!

Comment: just shows that beauracracy effects has no language barriers haha.

Comment: My teacher told me that it could have been Least Developed Countries haven't been 脱贫摘帽，what do you say?

Comment: 脱贫摘帽的意思是摆脱贫困状态，不再属于贫困行列。2020年我国彻底打赢了脱贫攻坚战。但是，脱贫摘帽不是终点，而是新生活新奋斗的起点。Nations which have not shaken off poverty have not shaken of poverty and can be categorised as Least Developed Nations. This is not a logical step, such nations are definded thus! That's why the above Officialese is ridiculous!